# Delete [analysis] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently encountered [analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) and found it to be a bit confusing and unnecessary, despite the detailed tag info. I then discovered this meta thread about it from 2015 that proposed creating the tag:

[Create [analysis] tag? + Update 2017: Delete [analysis] tag?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/create-analysis-tag-update-2017-delete-analysis-tag)

An [answer by amoeba in 2017 proposed deleting it](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4557/121522). I won't rehash the arguments here but based on the votes there seems to be support for getting rid of it. For what its worth, AdamO (who proposed its creation) states in a comment on that answer "[I can say in confidence that my tag did not help](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/create-analysis-tag-update-2017-delete-analysis-tag#comment11981_4557)".

Since 2017, the tag has grown from 171 to 465 questions. Shall we get rid of it?

Comment: It's likely too late. This would mean that someone would need to go through all 465 questions and remove the tag from each, while each of them would bump to the main page because of being "edited". Unless someone is willing to delete it in 10 Q/day rate every day for the next 46 days...

Comment: @Tim Is it okay if I do this?

Comment: feel free, just keep in mind that recommended way is to do this just a few Q at a time so the Qs with edited tags do not flood the main page.

Comment: @Tim Done. Anything else to be done? Like perhaps editing the tag info to warn against using it?

Comment: That's great, thanks!